# How to find Retain Count of the Objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am new to Objective-c.I want to know the retain count of the following objects and also I would like to know the process also how it is working.
I studied so many documents and watched tutorials also but this doubt remains me like that only.

```
NSString *str1=@"Hai";
NSString *str2=str1;
NSSstring *str3=[str2 copy];
```

What is the retain count of that "three strings"?

Sorry for my horrible English.
Can anyone please tell me the answer.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please use the search feature first.  This is not the first time this has been asked and you will now receive a whole batch of downvotes and flippant links to [http://whentouseretaincount.com](http://whentouseretaincount.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *str1=@"Hai";
NSString *str2=str1;
NSSstring *str3=[str2 copy];

NSLog(@"COUNT %lu",(unsigned long)[str1 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"COUNT %lu",(unsigned long)[str2 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"COUNT %lu",(unsigned long)[str3 retainCount]);
```

Comment: It is not working.It is showing Error
"ARC forbids  explicit message sent to retain count"

Comment: What error ? are you using ARC ?
Obviously it will show an error. It will work only in case of without ARC

Comment: Why for every string retain count is coming 1?Can yoy please tell me the answer?